# Deleting an item from dictionary deep in the level

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary of arrays which further contains dictionary. I want to delete one key inside the innermost dictionary. What is the easiest and fastest way for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Simply access the inner dictionary as if it weren't inside an array inside a dictionary.

For instance:

```
[[[settingsDictionary objectForKey:@"key1"] objectAtIndex:index] removeObjectForKey:@"key2"];
```

or more spread out:

```
NSArray *innerArray = [topDict objectForKey:@"key1"];
NSMutableDictionary *innerDict = [innerArray objectAtIndex:index];
[innerDict removeObjectForKey:@"key2"];
```

or using the new subscript notation:

```
[settingsDictionary[@"key1"][index] removeObjectForKey:@"key2"];
```

There's really no special way to do this that I can think of, just access the object and call the removeObjectForKey method.

Comment: I can verify that there is no less verbose way to do this. Welcome to Cocoa! :P

Comment: It's worth noting that there is now subscript-notation to make this much more compact.

Comment: Too funny that you commented this right now! I was literally just editing the example to include subscript-notation, but got distracted for a moment in a meeting so haven't posted it yet. :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that for this structure there is an other way that getting the key of your array, then the index in your array and the key of the element you want to delete.